# Is there a way to combine 2 or more events that do similar operations to use the DRY principle

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have two events one is a key press and the other is a click event. the events do similar thing but they are different(ex: they search for different elements and in my real code they call diff functions depending on which button and which input box was entered) . should i combine the events? if so how?

```
      $(document).ready( function(){
        function replaceQ(){
            var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() *10)
            var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *10)
            $(".container").children().remove()
            $(".container").append("<div>" + num1 + " </div><div>" + num2 +"</div>")
                    .append("<input class='input'>").append("<button class = 'button'>Go</button>")
            var result = num1 + num2;
            return [result]
        }
        var outResult = replaceQ()[0]



        $(".container").on("click", "button", function(){
                var entry = $(this).siblings(".input").val()
            if(outResult == entry){
                outResult = replaceQ()[0]
            }
        })
        $(".container").on("keypress", "input", function(e){
            var entry = $(".input").val()
            if(outResult == entry && e.which == 13){
                outResult = replaceQ()[0]
            }
        })
        var processAnswer = function processAnswer(e){
            //if(e.target.className === "input")  
        }

        $(".input, .button").on("click", processAnswer)

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listeners themselves are separate enough that it would probably make more sense to just make a single function for the handler. So part of your code would look like this:

```
//New Event Handling function
function eventHandler(e) {
   var entry = $(".input").val()
    if(outResult == entry && (!e.which || e.which == 13)){
        outResult = replaceQ()[0]
    }
}

    $(".container").on("click", "button", eventHandler);
    $(".container").on("keypress", "input", eventHandler);
```

I don't think it makes sense to combine the event listeners as they are listening to specific elements and combining them (like `$(".container").on("click keypress", eventHandler);`) could get weird as it would trigger when you click on a text field. So for that reason, I'd focus on combining the handler like above.

Comment: thanks for your help. `!e.which` is for when the enter isn't pressed? that or statement basically allows us to use this function for the keypress and the button click? i never used !e.which

Comment: `!e.which` checks to see that the `which` property was not set (which would happen on the mouse click). So basically it's saying that either the which property must not be set, or if it is set, it must equal 13

Answer (score 2):

you can get `Event.type` in callback function, see below sample code

```
var processAnswer = function processAnswer(e){
  if(e.type == 'click'){
    //code here
  }
  else if(e.type == 'keypress'){
    //code here
  }
}

$(".input, .button").on("click keypress", processAnswer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is. You can use the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method as follows:

```
$(".container button").bind("click keypress", function(){
    ....
});
```

**edit**

You can check wether the button or the container was triggered as follows

```
$(".container button, .container input").bind("click keypress", function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if(target.is('button'))
    {
        alert("button");
    }
    else if(target.is('input'))
    {
        alert("input");
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirtzbruch/7o5bqo05/) for example.